# add seperate suffix for low price and high price in woocommerce

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

just trying to figure out how to add a suffix to prices that are lets say:

$10 - $100

on the shop page to something like:

$10 (a) - $100 (b)

the only thing i found makes it

$10 - $100 (a) - (b)

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','pd_add_price_per_unit_meta_to_price');
function pd_add_price_per_unit_meta_to_price( $price ) {
    $price .= ' aasdf ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wc_price_per_unit_key', true);
    return $price;
}
```

but it displays this on each price variation and i don't want this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You cloud use the filter ["woocommerce_format_price_range"](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_format_price_range.html#1155-1166) from the "wc_format_price_range" function to modifed the price.

A small example:

```
function my_function_to_change_the_price_formating($price)
{
    // If you look in the function wc_format_price_range, you will see that the two prices are separated by a dash. (&ndash;)
    // We used this "dash" and separate the two prices.
    $tmp = explode('&ndash;', $price);

    // And now we'll put it back together with the custome text.
    return trim($tmp[0]) . ' (a) &ndash; '. trim($tmp[1]) .' (b)';
}

add_action('woocommerce_format_price_range', 'my_function_to_change_the_price_formating');
```

[image: Shop item with the custome variation prices]